# Another installing Yesod on Ubuntu difficulty

Tags: haskell, ubuntu, yesod

Looking around StackOverflow I see a bunch of similar problems, but each about a specific library.

Here's mine :

When trying to run :

```
cabal install yesod
```

I get

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring yaml-0.8.7...
Building yaml-0.8.7...
Preprocessing library yaml-0.8.7...

Data/Yaml/Parser.hs:15:8:
    Could not find module `Data.Conduit.Lift'
    Perhaps you meant
      Data.Conduit.List (from conduit-1.0.8)
      Data.Conduit.List (needs flag -package conduit-1.0.5.1)
      Data.Conduit.Text (needs flag -package conduit-1.0.5.1)
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed to install yaml-0.8.7
Configuring yesod-core-1.2.10...
Building yesod-core-1.2.10...
Preprocessing library yesod-core-1.2.10...

Yesod/Core/Json.hs:47:8:
    Could not find module `Data.Conduit.Lift'
    Perhaps you meant
      Data.Conduit.List (from conduit-1.0.8)
      Data.Conduit.List (needs flag -package conduit-1.0.5.1)
      Data.Conduit.Text (needs flag -package conduit-1.0.5.1)
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed to install yesod-core-1.2.10
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
yaml-0.8.7 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
yesod-1.2.5.2 depends on yesod-core-1.2.10 which failed to install.
yesod-auth-1.3.0.2 depends on yesod-core-1.2.10 which failed to install.
yesod-core-1.2.10 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
yesod-form-1.3.8.1 depends on yesod-core-1.2.10 which failed to install.
yesod-persistent-1.2.2.2 depends on yesod-core-1.2.10 which failed to install.
```

Is something broken in Hackage or is this just on my machine?

Comment: You mention Ubuntu, but you don’t tell us what packages you take from Ubuntu (just ghc? Or also some of the libghc-foo-dev packages, e.g. libghc-conduit-dev?) and what you have installed from hackage.

Comment: Update: Just realized I was giving wrong information. This message came from trying to install yesod with cabal. Only haskell-platform was installed with apt-get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to install a version of yaml that doesn't have a strict enough lower bound on conduit. There is a newer version already on Hackage. It looks like you haven't run `cabal update`.

Comment: It seems there's some kind of incompatibility between yaml and conduit. My cabal has been updated. If I try to install yaml by itself then it seems to work (I get yaml-0.8.8.1). If I try to then reinstall conduit I get :In order, the following would be installed:
conduit-1.0.17.1 (reinstall)
cabal: The following packages are likely to be broken by the reinstalls:
yaml-0.8.8.1

Comment: What happens if you try running `cabal install yesod-platform`? Overall, it sounds like you have a conflict between distribution-provided packages and what you're trying to install from Hackage, like @Joachim Breitner was getting at.

Comment: It tells me all the things that it would install. Then gives me a long list of things that "are likely to be broken by the reinstalls:" including yaml.0.8.8.1 and conduit-1.0.8 and conduit-1.0.17.1

Comment: Then you should go ahead with it. The package versions you have installed right now are not compatible with each other, so you'll have to break them in the reinstall process most likely.

Comment: Ah ok. Here's what worked :

apt-get removed yosad / haskell-platfrom / pandoc. 

apt-get reinstalled haskell-platform

cabal updated

cabal installed yesod platform

accepted install despite alleged incompatibilities.

Thanks @Michael Snoyman